# reasons problem with 3 variables

Tags: numerical-methods

If `a/3 = b/5 = c/2`and `a + b + c = 40`, so `3a + b – 2c`

It is a problem of reasons and proportionality, which I still can not solve, can someone explain to me how to arrive at the correct result?
w why

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Suppose $c=2k$ ($k$ is probably an integer, but might not be). Then $a=3k,b=5k$, so $a+b+c=10k$, so $k=4$. If you don't like that, then simply express $a,b$ in terms of $c$: $a=3c/2,b=5c/2$.

Comment: @almagest why not change that to an answer?

Comment: @JohnDoe Because it is completely trivial.

Comment: @almagest yes, but what is trivial to one person may not be trivial to someone else. Besides, it answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a/3$ = $c/2$

$a= 3c/2$

$b/5$=$c/2$

$b=5c/2$

If $a+b+c=40$ then $(3c/2)+ (5c/2) + c = 40$

$c=8$

Putting this on the other 2 equations

$b=20$

$a=12$

$3a+b-2c = 3\cdot 12 + 20 - 2\cdot 8 = 40$